# UItableview reload animation from bottom to top

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation

I have a grouped UITableView with section headers and want to animation that group of tableview should animate from bottom to top, is it possible to do that?

Comment: Animate starting from last indexPath to first

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
@IBOutlet weak var tblVw: UITableView!

func animateTable(tblVW: UITableView) {
        tblVW.reloadData()

        let cells = tblVW.visibleCells
        let tableHeight: CGFloat = tblVW.bounds.size.height

        for i in cells {
            let cell: UITableViewCell = i as UITableViewCell
            cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: tableHeight)
        }

        var index = 0

        for a in cells {
            let cell: UITableViewCell = a as UITableViewCell
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0.05 * Double(index), options: .allowAnimatedContent, animations: {
                cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0);
            }, completion: nil)
            index += 1
        }
    }


override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
         animateTable(tblVW: tblVw)
    }
```

Comment: it is ok for cells, but sections headers appear first and then cells appear from bottom to top.

Answer (score -1):

Just change it by tableView

```
func animateTable(tableView: UITableView) {

    let tableViewHeight: CGFloat = tableView.bounds.size.height
    tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: tableViewHeight)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0.05, options: .allowAnimatedContent, animations: {
        tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0);
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

And you will move the full tableView, not just the cells